# R commands to find SNP density from VCF file , or aligned FASTA file

Tags: r, genome

I face some issues to find the SNPs density from the VCF file which have the SNPs, I am using the following commands without any error but no result show.

I face some issues to find the SNPs density from the VCF file which have the SNPs, I am using the following commands without any error but no result show
R command :

```
snps<-read.table("C:/Users/Hamza/OneDrive/Desktop/snp/faiqa.vcf",sep="\t",header=F,blank.lines.skip=TRUE,
                 comment.char = "#")
colnames(snps)<-c("CHROM","POS","ID","REF","ALT","QUAL",
                  "FILTER","INFO","FORMAT")
library(ggplot2)
snpDensity <- ggplot(snps) + geom_histogram(aes(x=POS),binwidth=1e4) + ggtitle("Density of SNPs") + facet_wrap(~ CHROM, ncol=2) + xlab("Position in the genome") + ylab("SNP density")

pdf("snp_density.pdf",800,1000)
print(snpDensity)
```

Comment: Provide example data, `dput(head(snps))`.